# estoy clonando repo de git en el cmd; ingreso a la carpeta del proyecto por cmd e instalo "yarn" despues a comprobar ng serve y salta error!?

Tags: angular, cmd, yarn

Después de instalar el `yarn` compruebo con `ng server` y salta este error?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer es un problema con [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532) y `Node 17`. Usando la versión estable de `Node` (actualmente la 16) se solucionará el problema.

Alternativamente según [esta solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69753727/8838721), el problema se desaparece colocando en el `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider; ng build"
  }
}
```

Pero lo recomendable ejecutar **SIEMPRE** el proyecto con una **versión estable** de tus librerías, por lo que, de manera preferente, instala `Node 16`.